# VBA: "Variable not defined" error on Protect method for Worksheet object

Tags: excel, vba

I had a very simple protect worksheet method which was functioning.

`Worksheets("Sheet 1").Protect "P@ssw0rd"`

Adding the following causes the code not to compile, giving me "Variable not defined"

`Worksheets("Sheet 1").Protect "P@ssw0rd", AllowSorting = True, AllowFiltering = True`

I'm confused, because [my code seems to match the Microsoft support syntax.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Protect)

Comment: It does not match the syntax, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments).

Comment: A named argument consists of an argument name followed by a colon and an equal sign (**:=**), followed by the argument value.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was helpful. I had tried it with := but with parenthesis added and was getting a different error

Comment: Don't use parentheses on a sub or method call. In VBA, parentheses are for calls that result in a return value, one which is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

As Storax pointed out, I erred by using = rather than :=

This code works

`Worksheets("Sheet 1").Protect "P@ssw0rd", AllowFiltering:=True`